# nmap deleting user path

Tags: windows-10, path, nmap

It's not much of a question that a warning, but still i was wondering if someone faced this issue.

I downloaded and installed the latest stable version of nmap (7.70) on my windows dev machine (i needed to check if a port was opened, even if i eventually found out the issue without using nmap).

I just noticed something EXTREMELY annoying : the nmap install replace my user PATH env var value by a unique "C:\path\to\nmap" ! (lucky for me, most of my build tools are defined in my system wide path, but i had a little moment of panic when i could not call one my build tools)

I strongly think it is related to the nmap installed (obviously, giving the new path value), but i could be wrong.

Does anyone had this issue ?

In advance, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/1396) in the Nmap 7.70 installer. If you choose "Register Nmap Path" and your `PATH` system variable exceeds 1024 bytes, it is overwritten. This is fixed in the Nmap 7.80 installer, which enforces the use of the NSIS "large strings" build to avoid this issue in the future.